# Smarty spacify modifier

Tags: php, smarty, modifier

I'm currently reading a book about *Smarty* technology. There's this modifier "*spacify*" which insert a character or a string (by default a single space character) between every characters of given string.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.spacify.tpl

Neither in the book or on the internet I can find a concrete example where this modifier could actually be useful...

Yet, there should be a reason for such a modifier to exists. Is anyone can provide me a concrete example?

Comment: **Note**: The book (Smarty PHP template programming and applications)  says "No practical use in english"...

Comment: It's a rather silly modifier, I doubt anybody uses it

Comment: Considering the book I'm reading was written in 2006 (9 years ago), I doubt the developers would had carry something no one use for so long or even built something utterly useless to begin with. There's must be some kind of need behind that it's conception.